# Remove event listeners in a foreach with a function passing arguments

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, removeeventlistener

I need to remove multiple event listeners (by calling the method destroy) but to do this I have to have the function *external*. The problem is that this function has to pass 2 arguments (`e` and `item`) and I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.Accordion.clickHandler

because, I think, the `item` variable doesn't already exist (because it will be passed by the `forEach`).

Here my code:

```
export default class Accordion {

  constructor(el) {
    this.accordion = el;
    this.items = el.querySelectorAll('.accordion__item');

    // Specify a *unique* function for add and remove the event.
    this.clickHandler = (e) => this.onClickBtn(e, item);

    // Create click events
    this.bindEvents();
  }

  bindEvents() {
    // Create a click event for each item
    this.items.forEach(item => {
      let btn = item.querySelector('.accordion__btn');
      btn.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler);
    });
  }

  destroy() {
    this.items.forEach(item => {
      let btn = item.querySelector('.accordion__btn');
      btn.removeEventListener('click', this.clickHandler);
    });
  }

  onClickBtn(e, item) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // DO THINGS
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is `item` in the constructor?

Comment: @TechySharnav There isn't. I'm just asking how to handle this situation

Comment: How about passing `undefined` instead of `item`?